# How to connect frontend to a node

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain

I created 2 nodes . I connect an accounts to metamask. I connect the smart contract with remix on the node. Now i am trying to connect frontend with the smart contract with web3. In the index.html i write :

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

// set the provider you want from Web3.providers
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://ip:8545"));

and then i run in my browser th index.html but i press buttons and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Panos, add this code to your javascript file and change networks to your custom RPC from your metamask. After that, you will be connected to your localnode from your browser.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            // Request account access if needed
            await ethereum.enable();

            web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts){ 
              if(!err){
                alert('Your Metamask account is: ' + accounts[0]);
              }           
            })

        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
        }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

        web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts){ 
          if(!err){
            alert('Your Metamask account is: ' + accounts[0]);
          }           
        })
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
        console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }
});
```